# Google Map to OSMdroid

Tags: osmdroid

For a project at school we have to work on an android app. This project involves porting the app which is working with Google Map to OSMdroid in order to use openstreetmaps. Our method was to replace Google Maps classes by their equivalent in OSMdroid.
We don't know if it's a good idea as it's our first android project. But we are having troubles finding some classes, like the equivalent of the class Google Map (we've found IMap but it's an interface and we haven't found any class implementing it.)

So here is our question: Can our idea work ? If yes, do you know the equivalent to Google Map class in OSMdroid ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Osmdroid is almost full replacement of Google Maps v1, so the idea of replacing Google Maps classes with their equivalent could be good idea if the first app using Google Maps v1 but with Google Maps v2 things are different.
But yes! most of Google Maps functionalities supported by osmdroid. However, you need to convert the app by looking for how to implement each function using osmdroid not by replacing classes with equivalent.

About the second part of the question. No, there is no one class in osmdroid that support all functions that Google Map class provides, but you can find most of that class functions in different osmdroid APIs.

For a good sample on how to use osmdroid take a look at OpenStreetMapViewer sample project https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer